# How to toggle from Celsius to Fahrenheit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a toggle button from Celsius to Fahrenheit in my app. I'm getting the value as props from OpenWeatherMap in an Axios call.
 This is my Toggle button:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <label className={Styles.switchWrap}>
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          value={this.value}
        />
        <div className={Styles.switch}></div>
      </label>
    )
  }
}`
```

And this is my Weather component with the function that I'm trying to make to convert all the props into Fahrenheit and back and the Toggle component.

```
const Weather = (props) => {

  const toggleCF = () => {
    let arrayTemp = [props.temp, props.forecast, props.forecast2, props.forecast3]
    if (this.checked) {
      return arrayTemp = this.arrayTemp
    } else {
      return arrayTemp.map( t => t * 9 / 5 + 32)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={Styles.outputs}>
      {props.id&& props.country && <div className={Styles.fontIcon}><i className={`owf owf-${props.id}`}></i></div>}
      {props.city && props.country && <h2 className={Styles.outputCity}>{props.city}, {props.country}</h2>}
      {props.main && props.description && <div className={Styles.outputDesc}>{props.main}/{props.description}</div>}
      {props.id&& props.country && <>
         <p className={Styles.toogleDegrees}>C/F</p>
         <Toggle
           value={props.value}
           onChange={toggleCF}
         />
      </>}
```

I've been so stuck on this that I don't think anything make any sense anymore.
Any help?

Comment: You should store store data like that in component state. You can't return it from a function.

Comment: I'm very new, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Have you read through the React docs? In particular https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html relates to what @Andy is saying.

Comment: why did you write value={this.value}/> inside your toggle component, i think it should be this.props.value instead